# Resend a message stored in error queue with RabbitMQ

Tags: c#, .net, rabbitmq, nservicebus

I'm new to RabbitMQ and I'm using it with NServiceBus.I already searched in google but could not find anything that could help me.

Does anyone know if you can send a specific message, taken from the error queue, to a specific queue (destination)?

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you very much.

Comment: I've never used NServiceBus but you can definitely do that with RabbitMQ, see http://www.rabbitmq.com/getstarted.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ServiceInsight](http://docs.particular.net/serviceinsight/getting-started-overview) and [ServicePulse](http://docs.particular.net/servicepulse/introduction-and-installing-servicepulse) to do that.

HTH